# How to wait for an asynchronous task to return

Tags: java, android

So I have a problem and I am wondering how to solve it if it can be solved at all.

I have an external library class called Messenger that defines the method sendMessage(String msg). I also have the following MessengerManager class

```
public class MessengerManager{

    private Messenger messenger;

    public MessengerManager(Context context){
         messenger = new Messenger(context);
    }

    public void message(){
         String msg = "12435";
         messenger.sendMessage(msg);
         // Do more stuff
         .....
         .....
         .....
    }         
}
```

So the issue is that sendMessage runs asynchronously and starts a new activity. Probably using startActivity() (lets call this Activity A). Hence, the code after sendMessage ("Do more stuff") gets run immediately. However, I need to wait for the newly created activity (Activity A) to return to carry on with the "Do more stuff".

As sendMessage is a method defined in an external library, I cannot change it in any way nor do I have access to its source code.

So, in short, my problem is that sendMessage creates a new thread (using startActivity() probably) and I need to know when this newly created activity ends. However, I have no way of monitoring it since it is defined in an external library. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I have tried the AsyncTask suggestion but it does not work. I have sendMessage inside of my doInBackground(). The problem is that sendMessage() creates an activity and returns (probably calls startActivity()). Now I need to wait for the completion of this newly created activity. However, since sendMessage() returns, the AsyncTask continues to the postExecute().

Answer (score 4):

AsyncTask should be what you are looking for.
Let your *message()* starts an AsyncTask that calls *messenger.sendMessage(msg)* in *doInBackground()*. If you care about the result of the AsyncTask, get it in *onPostExecute()*.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: So does Async Task block the Main UI thread until it returns? Because I do not want the "Do more stuff" code to execute before sendMessage() returns.

Comment: No, AsyncTask runs in separate thread from main UI thread. AsyncTask will start a new thread and return immediately. The new thread does the *messenger.sendMessage(msg)* work.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you use it. Anything in `doInBackground()` will run on a separate thread. All of the other methods of `AsyncTask` run on the main thread

Comment: @codeMagic Yes. Thanks for clarification. Only doInBackground() runs in another thread.

Comment: If the AsyncTask runs on a separate thread, then won't execution in the main UI thread continue to the "Do more stuff" code?

Comment: @nave Yes, main UI thread will continue immediately to the "Do more stuff" code.

Comment: @kaifei Well, unfortunately, that won't help then. I would like for the main UI thread to halt execution until the background thread is done. Is there a way? I'm thinking possibly through wait() and notify()?

Comment: @nave You can continue "Do more stuff" in *onPostExecute()*, which is called in main UI thread after the background job is done.

Comment: I have tried the AsyncTask suggestion but it does not work. I have sendMessage inside of my doInBackground(). The problem is that sendMessage() creates an activity and returns (probably calls  startActivity()). Now I need to wait for the completion of this newly created activity. However, since sendMessage() returns, the AsyncTask continues to the postExecute().

Comment: @nave Is `sendMessage()` your own code or a third-party library?

Comment: @nave If the sendMessage starts a new activity, your current activity will be paused and stopped (and onPause and onStop will be called). And you should be able to see a new activity on your device screen. When your current activity comes back, you can do "Do more stuff" in the onResume() or onRestart(). But I think it is really weird that a method called *sendMessage()* starts a new activity.

Answer (score 2):

One admittedly ugly way to get around this is to call 
Thread.sleep(int milliseconds)
after sendMessage(), and before you continue with the rest of your code. Of course, this will only be helpful if you can fairly accurately estimate how long it will take to get the callback.

The better alternative is as Kaifei is saying. But you won't want the "do more stuff" where it is now. Instead, put it in a new method, and call that method in onPostExecute(). That way, the code will not continue until the AsyncTask has returned.

Edit: Saw your addition about needing the created activity to finish. If that's the case, you're going to somehow need to communicate with that activity (which I can't speak to without seeing all the code). But if you have that, then before "do more stuff", insert

```
while(!activity.isFinished()) {}
```

and in that activity, have it set a finished variable to true when it is done (however you define done). So the main thread will run this loop until the activity on the second thread is done, and then the first thread will continue.

Double Edit: Another idea. Let's say that the other activity the user has to complete is some form. In your main activity, after you call sendMessage(), have some popup where the user selects "finished" when they have completed the new activity. Have the program only continue when "finished" has been selected. A bit annoying for the user, but if it's only a single additional tap, that should work.

Comment: Also the sendMessage() method needs access to the UI thread (it brings up a dialog to which the user needs to respond to). Will this work with AsyncTask?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't, but I don't have a terrible amount of experience with AsyncTask, so I can't say for certain. I'd say try it out and see what happens?

Comment: as it is a 3rd-party library, I cannot even view the implemention of sendMessage or the activity, let alone introduce any new code in it. In essence, sendMessage() is a blackbox. All I know about it is that it creates an activity which I need to wait for to finish.

Comment: @nave That seems...impossible to get around. So I guess the only thing I got is my first suggestion, of having some sleep or wait method.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but the newly created activity waits on user input to finish. So I have to real way of estimating how long this might take. So, the sleep option also wont work im afraid

Comment: @nave Soooo let me get this straight. You need to figure out when an activity finishes. You have no access to the activity, no callback from the activity when it finishes, and no way to know how long it will take for it to finish?

Comment: correct. As I indicated in the original question, I wasn't sure if this was doable.

Comment: @nave Another attempt :D

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `sendMessage()` runs asynchronously. If it's written properly, it must also have provided a callback interface, whose method will be called when messaging is finished. Move the code in that callback method.

Comment: Unfortunately, seems it wasn't written very properly. Documentation mentions nothing of a callback.